# What does [opt] mean in MSIL?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, cil, il

I found the "optional parameters" feature in C# 4.0 very interesting, so I tried to figure out how they made it happen.
so I wrote a method like this:

```
private static void A(int a = 5) { }
```

Compiled it, then decompiled it in IL DASM, this is the IL code:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  A([opt] int32 a) cil managed
{
  .param [1] = int32(0x00000005)
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method Program::A
```

And it has got this in its metadata:

(1) ParamToken : (08000002) Name : a flags: [Optional] [HasDefault]  (00001010) Default: (I4) 5

So I followed the clue and wrote a method like this:

```
private static void B([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(78)]int b) { }
```

Compiled it and decompiled it, and I found that the C# compiler generated almost the identical MSIL code for method A and B(except for the name).

As we can see there is no sign of attributes in the IL code and it felt wrong, so I wrote a custom attribute like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class MyTestAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then used it in method C like this:

```
private static void C([MyTest]int c) { }
```

Compiled it and then decompiled it, and hah, I found this:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  C(int32 c) cil managed
{
  .param [1]
  .custom instance void ConsoleApplication1.MyTestAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method Program::C
```

The second line of the method body calls to the ctor of my custom attribute.

So this leads to my doubts:

1. What does [opt] mean? I mean the one that appears in front of method A and B's parameter.
2. How come method C calls the constructor of the Attribute that is applied to its parameter and method A and B do not?
3. I can not seem to find any sign of DefaultParameterValueAttribute in the metadata, but I can find OptionalAttribute and MyTestAttribute. Why is that? Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C# compiler doesn't need to emit the attributes since the Param metadata table can already describe optional and default values via the `Flags` column.

From 23.1.13 in [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm):

```
Flag            Value   Description
-----------------------------------------------------
In              0x0001  Parameter is [In]  
Out             0x0002  Parameter is [Out]  
Optional        0x0010  Parameter is optional  
HasDefault      0x1000  Parameter has a default value  
HasFieldMarshal 0x2000  Parameter has FieldMarshal
```

A parameter can have a flag value that specifies it is optional and has a default value (0x0010 | 0x1000).  Parameters that have a default value will have an associated token in the Constant metadata table.

The Constant metadata table has a `Parent` column that would be the Param token in question and a `Value` column that would be an index into the blob heap where the default value is stored.

So to answer your questions:

1. [opt] means the `Flags` column for the Param token has the Optional flag set.
2. As I stated above, my guess here is that the C# compiler is recognizing the Optional/DefaultParameterValue attributes and simply converting them to parameter flags.
3. **Edit**: It appears that the C# compiler is emitting an unused TypeRef for OptionalAttribute, despite the Optional flag being used for the parameter.  It doesn't emit a TypeRef for DefaultParameterValueAttribute, though.  It could be a small compiler bug for emitting unused TypeRefs/MemberRefs.

Comment: Thanks, I did not expect to get an answer so soon. But yours seems like the one.

Comment: Wow, did not expect to find a bug of CSC.

Comment: @CuiPengFei: a presumed bug, at least.  There may be a valid reason for it doing so, but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Just found out VB.Net compiler does that too.

Answer (score 2):

2 / 3; there are a few attributes that the compiler interprets as IL metadata, not really attributes; it looks like this is the case here; `[Serializable]` is another example. The data for the default is there: `Default: (I4) 5` - not all attributes in code become attributes in the metadata (again, I'm looking at `[Serializable]` here)

---

re that point on `[Serializable]` (comments); here's an example:

```
[Description("abc")]
class Foo { }

[Serializable]
class Bar { }
```

for which the core IL is:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Foo
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .custom instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute::.ctor(string) = { string('abc') }
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
    }

}
.class private auto ansi serializable beforefieldinit Bar
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
    }

}
```

In `Foo` (for some arbitrary attribute), we get:

```
.custom instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute::.ctor(string) = { string('abc') }
```

However this does not apply for `[Serializable]`; instead, that is part of the type:

```
.class private auto ansi serializable beforefieldinit Bar
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. BTW, I saw your post when I was googling about "optional parameters", :)

Comment: I just tested it, actually, Serializable still appears in the metadata's reftype section.

Comment: @CuiPengFei - updating to illustrate

Comment: From ECMA-335, the latter would be a TypeDef with a Flag value with Serializable (0x00002000) set.

Comment: @CuiPengFei: indeed, from this example, I also notice that the compiler is emitting a TypeRef for the attribute, although it doesn't appear to be referenced.

Comment: @CuiPengFei: same thing for your example as well; the compiler appears to use the flags for Optional, but still emits an unused TypeRef for OptionalAttribute (doesn't appear to emit the TypeRef for DefaultParameterValue, though).  I guess this answers your #3 now that I see what you meant.